# How do I obtain a plot of $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ that includes $x <0$?

Tags: maple

I believe that the cubic root of $-8$ is $-2$, ie $\sqrt[3]{-8}=-2$, or $(-2)^3=-8$.

When I ask Maple to tell me what this cubic root is

```
root(-8, 3)
```

I get the result

$$2(-1)^{1/3}$$

In Maple, let's say that we want to plot $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$

```
plot(x^(1/3), x = -2 .. 2)
```

The result is

[image]

Why don't we see the portion of the graph where $x<0$?

Here is another example, of $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}$. When I plot the function in Maple

```
plot((x^2 - 1)^(1/3), x = -2 .. 2)
```

[image]

There is no graph between $-1$ and $1$. I must be making a silly mistake, because in my mind $g(0)=-1$.

Is there a reason for Maple not to give the expected results for cubic roots of negative numbers?

Comment: You might have some luck asking this question at [MaplePrimes](https://www.mapleprimes.com/)

Comment: Use the function surd.

Comment: I suppose one can write cubroot function which gives $x^{1/3}$ for $x\geq 0$ and gives $-(-x)^{1/3}$ for $x<0$.

Comment: Maybe you forget that $(-1)^{1/3}=e^{i\pi/3}$. I.e. you get complex numbers

Comment: About reason: $z^{1/3}$ is multi-valued function, maybe default setting of Maple is to give complex root for negative $z$. If you calculate $z^{1/3}$ as $|z|^{1/3}\exp (i \frac13 \arg z)$ and use principal value of $\arg z$ for negative real number $z=x<0$, then first root is $|x|^{1/3}\exp (i\frac{\pi}3)$ which is complex number.

Comment: @RonnyLandsverk But you also get complex values for $x^{1/3}$, $x>0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Do you really ? For real $x>0$ ?

Comment: The function surd works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, For example $1^{1/3}$ has the three values $1$, $e^{\pm2\pi i/3}$. Of course usually we just consider the real cube root, but again that doesn't show that $x<0$ is different from $x>0$; for any real $x$ we usually just consider the real cube root.

Comment: You specifically mention the call `root(-8,3)`. The Help page for the `root` command explicitly describes this situation and this very same example. It describes that `root` returns the principal root, with formula. It suggests using `surd` to get the real root here. `https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=root#info`

Answer (score 1):

See the Maple function `surd`.

`plot(surd(x,3),x=-2..2);`

[image: A]

`plot(surd(x^2 - 1,3), x = -2 .. 2);`

[image: B]